# Selenium : How to Keep Browser open after code ends

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing an automation task to click some webpages.
What i want is to use chrome browser after my coded work is done. I've done this by time.sleep() but i think there are other ways to do this... Is there any good ideas??

```
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://example.com")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="USER_ID"]').send_keys("id")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="PWD"]').send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn_Login"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jqg_grd_basket_1"]')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cb_grd_basket"]').click()

enrollment_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 6, 10, 20, 1, 0)
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
wait_time = enrollment_time - current_time
time.sleep(wait_time.total_seconds())
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn_basketSave"]').click()
alert = Alert(driver)
print(alert.text)

time.sleep(999999)
```

Comment: 1) Why do you need `options.add_argument("disable-gpu")`, `options.add_argument("disable-infobars")` and `options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")`? 2) Doesn't `options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)` does the intended job for you?

Comment: 1) I need fast speed so i used that options. 2) I thought so, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't use `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` it will keep open till you manually exit.

Comment: I don't  use both code but it closed...

Comment: Added full code of mine.